# JSON object reproduces itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table

I have this JSON which generates a table :

```
function show(json)
{
    var content = '<table id = "myTable" border = 1>';
    var counter;

    for(counter = 0; counter < json.length ; counter++)
    {
        content += '<tr><td class = "topics">' + json[counter]['topic_name'] + '</td>''</tr>';
    }
    content += '</table>';

    $('#table_here').append(content);

}
```

I call it two times : 
1st. here :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("admin.php", show);
```

Second when I add  something on the table:

When I add something, the new table appears below the old one, I want to lose the old one and see only the new one. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change

```
$('#table_here').append(content);
```

into

```
$('#table_here').html(content);
```

this will replace the entire content of `#table_here` element